# Why is not detecting my parametrized class type?

Tags: java, generics

I'm not a Java expert at all so I apologize if I'm doing something very silly. I'm trying to get the type of my generic parameter using this

```
public class TestClass<T> {
    public T testMethod() {
        Type type = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) type;
        Class<T> aClass = (Class<T>) paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

I'm getting this runtime error

> java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getGenericSuperclass` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass--), as its name suggests, returns a `Type` that represents the superclass of the class, not the class itself.

Here, `type` is the `Class` object for `Object`, not `TestClass`.

To get your own class's type parameters, use [the `getTypeParameters` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters--).

Comment: Definitively misunderstood the use of that method, silly indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what the method `getGenericSuperclass()` does. It is about the generic type of the super class, not of the class itself.

Here is an example of its usage.

```
public class TestClass<T> {

    // The generic type of the super class of SubClass is TestClass<String>
    public static class SubClass extends TestClass<String> {
        public void testMethod() {
            Type type = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            System.out.println(type);
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SubClass().testMethod();
    }
}
```

This program prints:

```
TestClass<java.lang.String>
```

What you appear to be trying to do (get the generic type of an *instance* at runtime) is actually impossible in Java due to type erasure.